# how can I change an iframe orientation on mobile devices that is nested inside another iframe

Tags: javascript, android, iframe

Ok, this may be a little confusing.

I have a content inserted as an iframe in an app. I do not have access to the app code or anything, and its a big hassle to ask for changes there.

So now I have this content and in it that is an iframe for another content (dont ask me why) that I need to rotate when the phone orientation changes. The app orientation is fixed to vertical.

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: My head hurts from reading that problem. Sorry to hear! Does the `window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientation)` approach not work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange

Comment: You have external content in a iframe, and you want that external content (only!) to be rotated when the user rotates their device?

Comment: Yes, something like that. its an iframe inside another iframe in an app. Only the iframe inside another should rotate...